# Using react-string-replace but the string is not getting overwritten for multiple replacements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set a string to be replaced but it only changes the last one, it ignores the previous replaced text

Plugin: [react-string-replace](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace)

This the official documentation

Multiple replacements on a single string
You can run multiple replacements on one string by calling the function multiple times on the returned result.

[image: Both should be replaced also]

```
import reactStringReplace from "react-string-replace";
import { baseUrl, ORG_REGEX, PRODUCT_REGEX } from "../../Util/Constants";
import axios from "axios";
import GlobalDialog from "../RightBar/GlobalDialog";
import { useState } from "react";
import SubproductItem from "../Products/Item/SubproductItem";
import OrgComponent from "../Org/OrgComponent";

const ReactStringReplaceWithRegex = ({ text, entityKey, messageKey }) => {
  const [productDialog, setProductDialog] = useState(false);

  const markMessageRead = async (key) => {
    if (!key) return;

    try {
      const result = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}message/read`, {
        msg_id: key,
      });

      if (result.status === 200) {
        //     TODO let use know message marked read
        console.log("message read");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("markMessageRead error ", e);
    }
  };

  const handleReactStringReplace = (textToReplace) => {
    let replacedText;

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(textToReplace, ORG_REGEX, (match, i) => (
      <OrgComponent key={`${i}_${match}`} orgId={match.replace("Org/", "")} />
    ));

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(textToReplace, PRODUCT_REGEX, (match, i) => (
        <span
          key={`${i}_${match}`}
          style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid var(--lc-green)" }}
          onClick={() => {
            setProductDialog(true);
            markMessageRead(messageKey);
          }}
        >
          View Product
        </span>
      )
    );

    return <div>{replacedText}</div>;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {handleReactStringReplace(text)}

      <GlobalDialog
        size="md"
        removePadding
        hideHeader
        show={productDialog}
        hide={() => setProductDialog(false)}
      >
        <div className="col-12">
          <SubproductItem
            hideMoreMenu
            hideDate
            smallImage={true}
            productId={entityKey}
          />
        </div>
      </GlobalDialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default ReactStringReplaceWithRegex;
```

So what and I doing wrong here? and how can I get it to work?